# Creating the URDF in the PR2 MoveIt! Example

Tags: urdf, moveit, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am attempting to follow the tutorial on MoveIt! using the [PR2 example](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/PR2/Setup_Assistant/Quick_Start) in ROS Hydro.

However, it talks about using the URDF file generated "above":

*Click on the browse button and navigate to the pr2.urdf file you just created [above](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/PR2/Setup_Assistant/Quick_Start#Pre-requisites). Choose that file and then click Load Files. The Setup Assistant will load the files (this might take a few seconds) and present you with this screen:*

The 'above' link goes to a section on pre-requisites. This page contains no information on creating the URDF. The URDF file contains the `xacro` macros but I can find no clear instructions on actually creating it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190807/creating-the-urdf-in-the-pr2-moveit!-example/) by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2014-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Bjem,

If you look at the newer version of the tutorial posted here,
http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/moveit_setup_assistant/html/doc/tutorial.html

It says:
*This file gets installed in /opt/ros/hydro/share/pr2_description/robots/pr2.urdf.xacro on Ubuntu with ROS Hydro.*

This would be the file that you use as the URDF.

---

Originally posted by [Benjamin.Nilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/20058/benjamin.nilson/) with karma: 48 on 2014-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-08-23**:
Thank you, I successfully completed the tutorial at the site you specified. It's a shame the 'mainline' documentation doesn't say this.